# Why the name coined for MARKUP LANGUAGE for SBML?

Tags: bioinformatics, systems-biology, computational-model

I'm get the confusion about  SYSTEM BIOLOGY filed.  `SBML` is refer to as `SYSTEM BIOLOGY MARKUP LANGUAGE` why we should called as `MARKUP LANGUAGE`? In HTML,XML and other field Mark up language mean particular function is declare into the Angular bracket like `<H1> for Heading Tag` this is displayed on the browser. Markup Language was actually developed for Wep application.

In other words, MarkUp language only displayed what we want., not display the simple mathematical function. Like, I need add function 1 + 1 which is display on the browser Markup language is not add, which is done by the CGI programming Like PERL,PYTHON, javascript.

So, in SBML(System Biology MarkUp language) Tools are not only display the what we want it? and It is not run on the browser? So why we called it is MarkUp Language?

Comment: I'm thinking you would do well to move this over to either the Computational Science or Programmers SE page. I down voted because of that. I think it is a good question. Just posted in the wrong location.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about biology.

Answer (score 4):

SBML follows in the same vein as XML, in that it provides a standardized and flexible method for structuring information. XML and its ilk aren't just for making web pages, they're for sending structured datasets between systems and programs (in fact, XML is a fairly common configuration format). Why? Because the structure makes parsing simple (well, simple-ish).

BTW, markup languages were not invented for the web, HTML was far from the first one. The origin of markup languages is typesetting and in fact one of the most common uses these days is still in writing papers (ask a local math/physics/CS person what he/she uses to write papers and the answer will be Latex...a markup language).

**Edit**: BTW, this really has nothing to do with biology and you could have at least read the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) on what a markup language is.